# How to calculate difference between two date() in c#?

Tags: c#

I want code for to calculate the difference between two Dates..?

```
private void btnSaveHireCustommer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtMaximumKM.Text = dateTimePicker1.Text - dateTimePicker2.Text; 
}
```

Comment: You are attempting to perform arithmetic on text/strings.

Comment: The commends by Magnetron and 3Dave are incorrect. You should not do that. The correct solution is to use `Value` rather than `Text`. The difference between two values is a time span; you can then extract the necessary information from that to create a string.

Comment: Given that these are DateTimePickers, I'd *hope* there's a `Value` property or similar of type `DateTime`, so that parsing isn't required. But it would help if you could tell us what sort of arithmetic you want to perform. Please provide a sample scenario and your desired output.

Comment: @EricLippert I've been in C++ land for awhile. My bad.

Comment: @EricLippert yeah my bad, didn't see was a `DateTimePicker`, saw `Text` and my brain thought `TextBox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

`txtMaximumKM.Text = dateTimePicker1.Text - dateTimePicker2.Text;`

Do:

`txtMaximumKM.Text = (dateTimePicker1.Value - dateTimePicker2.Value).ToString();`

… you may also use the `ToString(string format)` overload to make it prettier.